# Xcode is auto-adding an info icon / "Accessory Button" to my table cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Lately, when I try to add a seque to my UITableView cell using the storyboard:

[image: Adding a seque]

Xcode is auto-adding an info icon / "Accessory Button" to the cell:

[image: Info icon]

I know I can remove it like so:

[image: Remove Accessory]

However, there appear to be [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569476/how-do-i-make-the-whole-cell-of-a-uitableview-respond-to-taps) that might also be symptoms of whatever is causing this behavior, but that's a separate question...  My question here is **why is Xcode adding it in the first place?**  It's never done this before when I've added storyboard seques...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During creation of the segue you have selected "Accessory Action" in the segue action popover. If you do this Xcode will set the accessory to "Detail Disclosure", because you need a tappable accessory to have an accessory action.

Select a Segue in the upper part of the popover. Those are Selection Segues, which are triggered when you select the cell.

[image]

---

This does explain your other issue as well. Because your segue is connected to the accessory, which you remove. So there is no way to actually trigger your segue.

Comment: I knew I had some noob mistake somewhere... Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select the cell and go to the attributes inspector
Scroll down to Accessory
In the drop down menu you will be having etail Disclosure selected
Change it to Disclosure Indicator
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **two different behaviors** for the segues. 
You can see them on your inspector: triggered segues.

- If you choose the accessory action, Xcode automatically add an accessory button (the circle).
- If you choose the selection action, you have no accessory button.